# SED excessive values from a text file

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Hello guys trying to figure out my **sed** command here:

INPUT from curl with ~25 sequences of this job:

```
XXXFC_BAR_MANAGER_API
API 20140603 0023 2182093 2082093 3 2
2014820906820903 10:02:54
2014820906820903 10:36:12
0:34:57

XXXFC_BAR_MANAGER_API
API 20140603 0022 2182093 2082093 3 2
2014820906820903 10:02:54
2014820906820903 10:36:12
0:34:57

XXXFC_BAR_MANAGER_API
API 20140603 0021 2182093 2082093 3 2
2014820906820903 10:02:54
2014820906820903 10:36:12
0:34:57
```

My sed: sed -e 's/API//' is removing API in both cases, also file has no structure so you can't awk it, I guess. These solutions are not working sed 's/^API //' and sed 's/^API //g' and sed -e 's/^API\s$//g'

So the output I am looking for all sequences is the following - the "API is gone from the "2nd line"

```
XXXFC_BAR_MANAGER_API
20140603 0021 2182093 2082093 3 2
2014820906820903 10:02:54
2014820906820903 10:36:12
0:34:57
```

Comment: What do you mean by "has no structure"? According to your comments to one of the answers below I am guessing that the data does not contain newline separators? This makes the example above non-representative and misleading. I think you should either update the question with a proper sample or perhaps upload a sample somewhere so we can have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/^API //' input
```

The `^` marks the beginning of a line. That's why the above command only removes occurrences of  `API<space>` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Seems that the output that I receive before applying sed is not structured so the entire thing is like a one line, so in my case this solution (sed 's/^API //' ) doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn't you have mentioned this in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an anchor point, `sed 's/^API//g'` . `^` anchors to a line start, `$` to a line end. You might add the space after the API.

Comment: The `/g` modifier makes no sense here. The beginning of a line can only occur once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the legit answer to this case:

```
sed 's/API\s2/2/g'
```

Substituting  2 from the date 2014 to 2 again so it gives the patter for SED to remove the value API 2!